# Best Practices/how to use SharePoint Logging?

Tags: logging

What are best practices for using Logging when you deliver a final product? So far I only really output the errors to \14\Logs\ using..

```
 SPDiagnositics.Local.WriteTrace(1, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("projectName", TraceSecerity.Unexpected,EventSeverity.None), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, "myMessage And/Or Error Message", null);
```

I intend to create a class to help me with error logging but I don't understand enough how to use this yet.

Also where do I find the results of

```
  SPDiagnostics.Local.WriteEvent(....)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i write to event viewer like so:

create an class project,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace EventViewerErrors
{
    public class reportError
    {    
        public reportError()
        {
        }

        public static void WriteError(string _LOACTION, string _EXCEPTION,string methodName, string _URL)
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                //EventLog.CreateEventSource("QuickLinks", "Application");
                EventLog.WriteEntry(_LOACTION, _LOACTION + " , Failed at: " + _URL + " , the method that failed was: "+ methodName + " , With the following exception: " + _EXCEPTION, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

make sure its strongly named by adding a key. to do that, click on "project" on the top menu and select "project properties". No goto "signing" and click new in the dropdown box. You need to enter name for the key and its password.

build your project.

now you can add the project dll to any other project! Do this by going into the reference's for the selected project, add reference, find the dll and add!

add this to top of class:

```
using EventViewerErrors;
```

now you can call it like so!

```
reportError.WriteError("Control ID: " + a.Source, a.Message, " CreateChildControls: at " + a.StackTrace, SPContext.Current.Site.Url);
```

works well in my case, that code above should give you an idea on what to do. The "a" varible is from the try/catch like so

```
try
{}
catch(Exception a)
{
    reportError.WriteError("Control ID: " + a.Source, a.Message, " CreateChildControls: at " + a.StackTrace, SPContext.Current.Site.Url);
}
```

also for uls follow this and add it to the project above (logging class)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/debugging-using-spdiagnosticsservice-in-sharepoint-2010/

like so:

```
    public static void errorUlsLogging(string _Message, string _StackTrace)
    {
        SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("My Category", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, _Message, _StackTrace);
    }
```

so my final code will look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace EventViewerErrors
{
    public class reportError
    {    
        public reportError()
        {
        }

        public static void WriteError(string _LOACTION, string _EXCEPTION,string methodName, string _URL)
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                //EventLog.CreateEventSource("QuickLinks", "Application");
                EventLog.WriteEntry(_LOACTION, _LOACTION + " , Failed at: " + _URL + " , the method that failed was: "+ methodName + " , With the following exception: " + _EXCEPTION, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
            });
        }

        public static void errorUlsLogging(string methodName, string _Message, string _StackTrace)
        {
            SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory(methodName, TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, _Message, _StackTrace);
        }

    }
}
```

for more flexability like adding method name ect look at:

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/logging-uls-sharepoint-2010/

to find the uls log its located at:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\LOGS

or download uls viewer

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer

Answer (score 1):

I have used and recommend Application Foundation for SharePoint 2010 and it has worked really well for me. It has a component called SharePoint Logger which takes care of logging to ULS for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798395.aspx

It takes a little while to get started with it but its worth the time.

Answer (score 1):

I used SharePoint Diagnostic logging for may of my projects.You can create your own Custom Areas and categories by inheriting from `SPDiagnosticsServiceBase` class. I have created a class which helps in logging to both ULS and Event Viewer.
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2011/10/sharepoint-2010-diagnostic-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

I never use SharePoint Logging system. I prefer to use Log4net. Check this link [Setup log4net for SharePoint based applications](http://www.thespgeek.com/2011/01/how-to-use-log4net-in-sharepoint-based.html)

Once you have referenced it in your VS project is very easy to Get More Detailed errors and take control in what you need